# MultiField mapping using spring-data-elasticsearch annotations

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use spring-data-elasticsearch to set up mappings for a type that is equivalent to the json configuration below and I am running into issues.

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "path" : "id"
    },

    "properties":{
        "addressName":{
            "type":"multi_field",
            "fields":{
                "addressName":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "edge":{
                    "analyzer":"edge_search_analyzer",
                    "type":"string"
                }
            }
        },
        "companyName":{
            "type":"multi_field",
            "fields":{
                "companyName":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "edge":{
                    "analyzer":"edge_search_analyzer",
                    "type":"string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the entity class as it stands now:

```
@Document(indexName = "test", type="address")
@Setting(settingPath="/config/elasticsearch/test.json") // Used to configure custom analyzer/filter
public class Address {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @MultiField(
        mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.String),
        otherFields = {
            @NestedField(dotSuffix = "edge", type = FieldType.String, indexAnalyzer = "edge_search_analyzer")
        }
    )        
    private String addressName;

    @MultiField(
        mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.String),
        otherFields = {
            @NestedField(dotSuffix = "edge", type = FieldType.String, indexAnalyzer = "edge_search_analyzer")
        }
    )        
    private String companyName;

    public Address() {}

    public Address(AddressDTO dto) {
        id = dto.getId();
        addressName = dto.getAddressName();
        companyName = dto.getCompanyName();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(id);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddressName() {
        return addressName;
    }

    public void setAddressName(String addressName) {
        this.addressName = addressName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}
```

What I am finding is that this results in a mapping like:

```
"address" : {
    "properties" : {
        "addressName" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
                "addressName.edge" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index_analyzer" : "edge_search_analyzer"
                }
            }
        },
        "companyName" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
                "companyName.edge" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index_analyzer" : "edge_search_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in two issues:

1. Id mapping is not done so Elasticsearch generates the ids
2. Searches on the properties with the custom analyzer do not work properly

If I add the following to override the use of the annotations everything works fine:

```
@Mapping(mappingPath="/config/elasticsearch/address.json")
```

Where "address.json" contains the mapping configuration from the top of this post.

So, can anyone point out where I might be going wrong with what I'm trying to achieve?
Is is possible using available annotations or am I going to have to stick with json configuration?

Also, is there a "correct" way to setup index-level configuration via spring-data-elasticsearch, or is that not a supported approach?  Currently, I am using the @Setting annotation for this purpose

Comment: Have you found an answer? I have the same issue.